# Is it possible to download my Facebook messages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Without** downloading a copy of my Facebook data.

I'd like to download my Facebook messages to be able to store them on my computer, search through them, etc. I downloaded a copy of my Facebook data with messages.htm. However, I have conversations with friends with over 250k messages, and not only will the messages.htm file never display because it's way too large, but looking through the HTML code, it seems to be missing messages.

Is there another way to go about this? Ideally I'd like to write a simple program which could do this. I looked into the Graph API but it seems impossible, for my purposes, to get the read_mailbox permission. If this is possible using the Graph API, or through any other means, I'd love to know!

Comment: _“but it seems impossible, for my purposes, to get the read_mailbox permission”_ – as long as only you are using the app, you don’t need to get permissions reviewed. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#roles

Comment: @ShaneOH I have an extension for Chrome for downloading FB messages, here's the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-chat-downloader/kflkdhmijdgjnlbdkfgdmolcjnflmlhf . But it works only on not such big conversations, so I'm still looking for a decision to download conversations in parts. I was looking in the direction of Graph API as well, but yesterday learned that the user's inbox won't be accessible any longer.

Comment: here's the changelog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4